# How do I edit selected tab control tab items?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, tabcontrol, roblox

I'm making roblox exploit in Visual Studio 2019 wpf and I have tab system which is adding and removing tabs and I add text editor when tab is added which is on my case AvalonEdit, but how do I detect selected tab and then edit the text editor for like clear button, save file button, open file button, inject dll button etc.

For example I would do the clear button like this(if I didn't have tab system):

```
AvalonEditor.Text = "";
```

But now I have the tab system idk how to do it so can anyone help me

[image: image of my roblox exploit]

Comment: So, each time a new tab is added you create a new editor for this tab, right? Could you please add code (or xml) that shows how exactly you create new tabs and add text editors?

Comment: @Igor ye it adds new editor when new tab added and the code is here:
`this.EditTabs.Loaded += delegate (object source, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                this.EditTabs.GetTemplateItem<Button>("AddTabButton").Click += delegate (object s, RoutedEventArgs f)
                {
                    this.MakeTab("", "New Tab " + this.EditTabs.Items.Count);
                };
            }`

Answer (score 0):

`if (TextEditor != null) { TextEditor.Clear(); }`

This should detect what tab the user is curentlly on and run a action on the avalon instance

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).